# Removing border of symbol in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a point layer in QGIS. I have created a
graduated color scheme, but it doesn't look good because
the border of all the symbols is showing and are overlapping (so you hardly see the color of the marker itself anymore).

Is there a way to remove the border of a standard symbol (symbol layer type: simple marker)?

The only thing I found with google was http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2012-March/015778.html, but that was not very helpfull for me (I don't find the Outline option to set to None)

I am using QGIS 1.7.4

**UPDATE: summary possible answers (thanks to @Marty and @SS_Rebelious):**

- Change the "Symbol layer type" from "Simple marker" to "Font marker" (in symbol selector window), select the '.' symbol and change the color.
- You can set the border color to the same RGB value as the fill color (but this is a lot of manual work if you have a graduated color scheme => you have to do it manually for each class).
- Another option is to use Old Symbology where you have the option to set the 'outline' to 'None'. However, the graduated color scheme is not as advanced as in the New Symbology (no color ramp to choose) and you have to set the outline for each class manually.

I used the first option, as this is the most automated way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:
Layer properties ->
Style ->
Change ->
And set the border color to something else.

Comment: Yes, but you can only choose a 'color' and not 'no color' or transparant or something like that. So that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You can set the border color to the same RGB value as the fill color.  Does that solve the problem? Or add a point from symbol markers collection, delete the simple marker and change the point marker's color to whatever suits.

Comment: That's a possibility, but as I use a graduated symbol style, I should change the border color manually for each class (after classifying), so that is not really convenient, but a possible solution for now.

Comment: Your second suggestion I do not understand. What is the symbol markers collection?

Comment: My bad, i ment the font marker. Change the "Symbol layer type" from "Simple marker" to " Font marker" (in symbol selector window), select the '.' symbol and change the color. Tried it out and it worked for me.

Comment: Indeed, that works! Only problem now is that the point '.' is a square and not a circle. And I don't find immediately a filled circle.

Comment: There's a round dot too. Probably in every font, but for sure in Arial, first row middle.

Comment: OK, I found one (after the arabic characters, the one in the first row is not recognised (a square) on my computer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Your another option is to use Old Symbology where you can create graduated symbols too. There are outline options available: see the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Aha! But I have two problems. 1) When I change the outline to None, and then press 'Classify', it changes back to the default settings (my change is not applied in the classifying). So I have to set it to None for each class individually. 2) How do I change the colors? Can I specify a color ramp?

Comment: 1) it is normal beheviour; 2) only manually, the colour is applicable only to new symbology.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but not seeing answers in other places and just did it for myself.

In Layer Styling under Symbol settings click on "simple marker":
[image]

In "Stroke Color" select "Transparent Stroke":
[image]

You can also change "Stroke Style" to "No Pen".

If you've formatted the symbology in other ways it should apply this change to all records in the layer.