# QGIS 2:14 - Border show-through on small Simple Markers

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, fields-attributes, markers

On small Simple Markers, `2.20000 mm` or less, there is border show-through which I have been unable to eliminate with `no pen` or `transparent border` style.

This is shown in the group of large and small circles in the screen shot below.

[image]

An [earlier post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32404/how-to-remove-the-border-of-a-symbol) suggested using Font Marker or an `SVG` but these also have border show-through on small Markers

Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: I think if you remove the 3rd simple marker in green with black border it may solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **Symbol Level** which sets the priority of specific symbols to render above or below others:

[image: Style options]

[image: Symbol levels]

Comment: @Adrian - Most welcome! Glad it worked =)