# Removing white border of polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I use the **graduated** color style for the polygons. But there are white borders between polygons. I tried to set **Border: transparant, Border stype: No pen, Border width: 0**. It did not work.

I found a similar question [Removing border of symbol in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32404/how-to-remove-the-border-of-a-symbol) It is about plotting the graduated **points**.

My current solution is setting the same border color with the polygon manually. But it needs a lot of time. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the border? Is it just a gap between adjacent polygons - put something coloured under it and see if the colour shows through. Also sometimes polygon drawing algorithms will leave blank pixels - these are hard to get rid of...

Comment: I fail to see how this is considered a duplicate when the OP clearly states: _"My current solution is setting the same border color with the polygon manually."_. The OP is looking for a more **automatic process**. The link to the 'possible duplicate' already describes a manual process which is probably what the OP is currently doing.

Comment: Here is another link on how to do it automatically: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/191035/63384, but it requires QGIS 2.14 and higher.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203468/removing-white-border-of-polygons-using-qgis explains the de-duplication/re-duplication history of this question.